# Custom property of own UserControl needs weird binding on usage

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, user-controls

We have a TickerUserControl with a simple Text property which stands for the displayed text of the ticker.

1. Do we really have to use these DependencyProperty pattern thing inside the UserControl (see below) or is there a simpler way to achieve this?
2. When we want to use our UserControl and BIND the text field to a property of a ViewModel we have to use the following weird binding syntax. Why can't we just use 'Text="{Binding Text}"' like all the other controls? Is there something wrong with the property implementation of the UserControl or something?

**Usage of the UserControl**

```
<userControls:TickerUserControl Text="{Binding Path=Parent.DataContext.TickerText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

**Property implementation of the UserControl (code behind)**

```
public partial class TickerUserControl : UserControl
{
    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); } 
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(TickerUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(""));

    // ...
}
```

**XAML snippet of the UserControl**

```
<UserControl x:Class="Project.UserControls.TickerUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}">

        <!-- ... -->
```

**The solution**

The problem was the setting of the DataContext inside the UserControl.
I deleted the DataContext binding added a name to the UserControl and modified the TextBox binding inside the UserControl. After that I was able to bind "as usual" from outside.

```
<userControls:TickerUserControl Text="{Binding TickerText}"/>

<UserControl x:Class="Project.UserControls.TickerUserControl"
             Name="TickerUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=TickerUserControl}">

        <!-- ... -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want to create bindable properties in the code behind of your `UserControl`, then **yes, you do have to use `DependencyProperty` objects**. However, you don't have to create your bindable properties there... you could use an MVVM type pattern and create your bindable properties in a separate class as long as you set *that class* as the `DataContext` of you `UserControl`.
2. **No, you don't have to use that 'weird' binding syntax**... the problem is that you have hard coded setting the `DataContext` of your `UserControl` to its code behind. Instead of doing that, you can bind your `Text` `DependencyProperty` in the control like this:

   ```
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
   {AncestorType={x:Type Local:TickerUserControl}}}" />
   ```

`Local` is the XML namespace of your local project... something like this:

```
     xmlns:Local="clr-namespace:Project.UserControls.TickerUserControl"
```

Then after removing the `DataContext` binding, you should be able to bind to the control from outside normally.

Comment: The key was your advice to the DataContext inside the UserControl which Daniel didn't mention but I find his approach more lightweight and easier to remember. Thank you Sheridan!

Comment: If you really don't want to select the answer that actually solved your problem, then at least add an update to your question outlining the full answer, so that you don't mislead other users looking for the actual answer.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that you mark my answer as correct... you are entitled to choose your own best answer. My only point was that you should make it clear to other users exactly what fixed your problem.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to bind your property, you'll need a dependency property.

To solve the weird binding you can do the following changes:

In your usercontrol

```
<UserControl Name="control"...
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=control}">
```

And then you can bind it like that

```
<userControls:TickerUserControl Text="{Binding TickerText}"/>
```

Comment: Yep. /signed. One missing point tought (which Sheridan mentioned later): I have to delete the binding of the DataContext inside the UserControl. I find your solution lightweight and easy to remember. Thank you!